# Does Kryonet library works with libGdx framework on Android?

Tags: java, android, networking, libgdx

I'm making a school project in which we can implement multiplayer on Android, and I've made some googling and my conclusion is that the libGdx's network functionalities aren't that good. So I came across this Kryonet library and people talk great about this one.
What I couldn't find is if this library works with Android, since it's a libGdx Android project.

Does it work then?
If someone has other sugestions as to which library to use to implement multiplayer, please share! :)

Comment: Yes, it does. People regularly post about it on the LibGDX user forums. The creator of Kryonet happens to be one of the two main project leads of LibGDX.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Now I can start using it then!